# C++ Linked List Add Node Onto the End

Tags: c++, linked-list

I seem to be having issues with the following segment and the latest exception I'm getting is:

Unhandled exception at 0x01321A01 in LinkedList.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000020.

I've been scouring google for hours, as well as my book and I can't seem to get the answers I need.

```
//add a node (pNode) at the tail of the list.  
//return a pointer to the head node
ListNode* addEnd( ListNode* pHead, ListNode* pNode )
{

    ListNode* pCurr = pHead;

    while( pCurr != NULL )
    {
        if(pCurr->pNextNode == NULL)
            break;

        pCurr = pCurr->pNextNode;

        if(pCurr->pNextNode == NULL)
            break;
    }

    pCurr->pNextNode = pNode;

    delete [] pCurr;

    return pHead;
}
```

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I guess the first question is, do you know what an access violation is? Do you know how one might be caused by code you write?

Comment: Not specifically, but if I were to take a guess, the issue is in the while loop

Comment: Refer to this:
http://www.c4learn.com/data-structure/insert-node-at-last-position-singly-linked-list/

Answer (score 1):

I think      `delete [] pCurr;` might cause the problem here

you are not suppose to delete pCurr here ,since you are not new any memory here, the temperary pointer will destroy itself at the end of the function , plus delete [] is for array.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would change the while loop and following code to be as follows:

`while (pCurr != NULL && pCurr->pNextNode != NULL)`
`{ pCurr = pCurr->pNextNode; }`

`if (pCurr != NULL)`
`{ pCurr->pNextNode = pNode; }`
`else`
`{ pHead = pNode; pNode->pNextNode = NULL; }`

`return (pHead);`

Ie, remove the `delete [] pCurr` line. For a start, you are using the array delete operator `delete []`, which is not correct (and that's why you are getting the access violation error). Secondly, you do not want to free the data pointed to by `pCurr`, as it is now one of the nodes in your linked list.

Answer (score 1):

First, stop deleting stuff. You're *adding* to this list. Second. If your list is empty (`pHead` is null) your code will invoke undefined behavior even without the `delete[]` (which should be taken out regardless).

There are multiple ways to do this, though I prefer the following, as it alleviates the need for a special-case head-is-null check

```
ListNode* addEnd( ListNode* pHead, ListNode* pNode )
{
    ListNode** pp = &pHead;
    while (*pp)
       pp = &(*pp)->pNextNode;
    *pp = pNode;
    return pHead;
}
```

Note: this assumes you're properly terminating your `pNode->pNextNode` pointer *before* coming in to this function (which you should be doing regardless).

**How It Works**

Pointers point to stuff. That may seem trivial to say, but the language allows you to have pointers to almost anything (not references). This includes other pointers. if this:

```
ListNode *p;
```

declares a a pointer to a `ListNode`, then this:

```
ListNode **pp = &p;
```

declares a pointer to a pointer-to-ListNode.

We use one of these, initially holding the *address* of the `pHead` parameter, to walk through the linked list, each step loading the *address* of the  `pNextNode` pointer from the current node. When we finally arrive at a pointer that is null we're pointing to the very `ListNode*` pointer we meet to set with `pNode`. As a bonus, this works even if `pHead` is null on inception, and you simply always return `pHead` as the function result (which, if the list was empty, is now populated with `pNode`)